What's the minimum indentation for "is_contributor: false"? Why indentation?
This comment below indented the Reddit AutoModerator rule / user check  "is_contributor: false" for 4 spaces. Why? Why can't you indent solely 1 space?
Why indent at all?

The is_contributor check needs to be indented under an author:, and
should say false instead of no :)
author:
    is_contributor: false


This is also indented by 4 spaces, but it doesn't outright moot indentation.


Why can't you indent solely 1 space?

Actually, you can. I just tried it.
The minimum required Reddit AutoModerator indentation is one space. Otherwise, Reddit wouldn't allow you to submit the AutoModerator rule, giving you the error message: 

Can't use is_contributor on this type in rule: […]



Why indent at all?

According to the Reddit Full AutoModerator Documentation, this is the syntax for karma and account age threshold checks under author: e.g., comment_karma and post_karma, and user checks such as has_verified_email and is_contributor.
